# How can I run a jQuery function using AS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3

I am trying to run a jQuery function on my HTML page from AS3.

This is my jQuery function:

```
function loadImage(imageNumber)
  {
    imageURL = '<img src="images/image' + imageNumber + '.jpg">';
    $("#imageBox").html(imageURL);
  }
```

Here are the settings of my flash file in the HTML page:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    
<embed src="links.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="320" height="242" name="links" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

and finally... here is the AS3 script in my .swf file:

```
function gotoImage1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var jscommand:String = "loadImage(1);"
    var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:" + jscommand + "");
    navigateToURL(link, '_self');
}
```

Thankyou in advance for taking the time to look and any help is massively appreciated.

Kindest Regards.Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ExternalInterface` instead:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call('function(){ alert("test"); }');
}
```

Documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: Thankyou for the fast response, although I got the alert("test") to show, I can not get my function to run. The function at the top of my HTML page is called "loadImage". I'm also passing a variable to this function.

if(ExternalInterface.available){
    ExternalInterface.call('loadImage(1);');
}

Comment: not to worry. ive got it working. Thankyou very much for the answer. Muchos appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The final solution was:

```
function gotoImage2(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(ExternalInterface.available)
    {
        ExternalInterface.call('function(){ loadImage(2); }');
    }
}
```

Just in case anyone wanted to see how it ended...

Comment: Why don't you call directly your javascript method instead of using an anonymous function? `ExternalInterface.call('loadImage', 2);`